# Having problems joining table

Tags: mysql, query, subquery

I have the following tables and I want to know Jack's `dob`, `salary` and the **total score** of that employee who is also a player.

The relational schemas are:

- ```
  Emp_Players (eid,pid,team) composite key is (eid,pid)
  ```
- ```
  Plays(pid, team, matchName, scores) composite key is (pid, team, matchName)
  ```
- ```
  Emp(empID, dob, salary) empID is pk
  ```
- ```
  Players(pid, name, team) composite keys are (pid, team)
  ```

The query that I wrote is this, however I get an error because I'm using `group by` operator.

```
Select name, address, dob, sum(scores)
From Emp e
JOIN Emp_Players ep ON e.empID = ep.eid 
JOIN Plays p ON p.pid = ep.pid
Group by p.pid;
```

Is there an alternate way that can work? Also I'm not sure if I'm doing the `JOIN` right? I am not able to use the `where` clause as `where name = 'Jack'`. It tells me

> 'no column named Jack'

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `GROUP BY` clause, you can only select the fields you group on, or aggregate functions on top of ungrouped fields, like so for example:

```
Select name, address, dob, sum(scores)
From Emp e
JOIN Emp_Players ep ON e.empID = ep.eid 
JOIN Plays p ON p.pid = ep.pid
Group by p.pid, name, address, dob
```

This will give you the sum of the scores for that player (`pid`) as you want if they only have one `name`, `address`, and `dob` per `pid`. But if they have two addresses for example, you'll see two records for that `pid`, one for each address, with the score summed for just that address. (I assume that's not the case here but just so you're aware. I was unsure since the schema you provided is incomplete and doesn't mention `address`.)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a more efficient way to do the same query? As I feel this is not that efficient.

Comment: @chimmy102 Not really, I think this would be the most efficient way (assuming it accomplishes what you're looking for). You can use **window functions** instead of the `GROUP BY` clause but that's probably overkill and possibly less efficient here. Why do you think this query is inefficient?